# Kohain First questions

Tags: halacha, kohen-priest, priorities

1)Is there a Din that a Kohain must be allowed to cut you online in a supermarket because of "Vkidashto"?

2)Do they go first when it comes to Davening when there are two Chiyuvim?

3)When you learn the Shach and Taz on Shulchan Aruch do you have to learn Shach first since he was a Kohain?

Comment: I was thinking should I turn this into three separate questions, Meanwhile if someone has an answer to a single aspect to the question it would be appreciated?

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/13553.

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/52581

Answer (score 5):

A kohein gets preference in:

- "open first" - in Torah reading or any matter of honor.
- "bless first"- he gets first grabs at a zimun (alt- to make hamotzi)
- "to take a nice portion first"

On the last example the Ran in [Nedarim (62b)](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=16&daf=62b&format=pdf) as well as Rashi in Gittin explain the case as splitting *equal* portions with a yisrael, where the kohen's choice is more of a subjectively nicer portion.

We see that a kohen cannot undermine another's rights.  If they're rights are equal, preference goes to the kohen. So to answer your questions:

1. No, he can't cut the line.
2. In theory, yes (also see Pri Megadim (Eshel Avraham) O.C. [53:14](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=41247&st=&pgnum=67)), but communities are allowed to override that rule when establishing a shul.
3. Sounds strange, but I don't have a source.

An interesting version of #2:  Since a Kohen has rights to the first honor, but not all the honor, if mincha and maarivv were davened in one shot, does the yisrael get to lead maariv?

Comment: As far as #3, the above rules do not apply to the _kohen_'s products, but to the _kohen_ himself. Perhaps it would be another thing if Rav Shabtai Kohen and Rav David [Halevi] Segel were actually standing in line waiting to present their _chidushim_.

Comment: Nice find in the Peri Megadim! Here is a follow up http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/13553/759

Comment: I don't understand #1. Why shouldn't the Yisrael allow him to cut the line? Merely because otherwise he'd get an unfair advantage of not having to wait? Isn't that the whole point of him going first?

Answer (score 3):

Question 3 was asked to Rav Yosef Chaim Sonnenfeld [here 105](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46247&st=&pgnum=161&hilite=), and he replied - without sourcing it -that there is no such obligation.